# How to get info from a node while inside in another node

Tags: xml, xslt

I'm new to XSL and while doing my master thesis I need to use this language. So as title says I need to use info from one node in another node. Here is a xml excerpt:

```
<pnml>
   <net id="1" name="park2in1out" type="IOPT">
     <arc id="5595" source="5583" target="5584">
        <type>normal</type>
        <graphics/>
        <inscription>
          <graphics>
            <offset page="1" x="-5" y="-10"/>
          </graphics>
          <value>1</value>
        </inscription>
      </arc>
      <conflict id="5756">
        <group id="0">
          <g_transition id="5551"/>
          <g_place id="5554">
            <g_arc id="5561"/>
          </g_place>
        </group>
      </conflict>
    </net>
  </pnml>
```

I need to use "value" tag value, while inside "g_arc".
Here is a excerpt of what already is done:

```
<xsl:for-each select="../conflict/group">
    <xsl:variable name="group_id" select="@id" />
        <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$group_id = 0">
         <xsl:text>          If </xsl:text>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:text>          Elsif </xsl:text>
        </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>


<xsl:value-of select="./g_transition" />
<xsl:variable name="transition_id" select="@id" />
<xsl:for-each select="./g_place">      
    <xsl:variable name="place_id" select="@id" />
    <xsl:text>(p_</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="$place_id" />
    <xsl:if test="type != 'test'">
        <xsl:text>_avail</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if> 
    <xsl:text> &gt;= </xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="./g_arc">
        <xsl:variable name="arc_id" select="@id" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="arc[@id=$arc_id]/inscription/value">
                <xsl:value-of select="number(inscription/value)" />
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="position() != last()">
            <xsl:text>+</xsl:text>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
</xsl:for-each>
```

So this is modified version of a code that was already made and for my master thesis I needed to modified it. Basically when I use "choose", I'm inside g_arc but I need to use "value" that is inside "arc". So I created the above code. Unfortunately the code generated (this is all done to generate code in VHDL) only outputs the value=1 even though the "value" tag of arc has value=2 or more. So I need to do a let say "regression" to the root to reach the arc to get the "value".

Thank you for your help

Comment: You are inside `g_arc` which is inside `conflict`. There could be many `conflict`s. You say you want the `value` from `arc` - but `arc` is a sibling of  `conflict` and there could be many `arc`s. You need to specify which `arc` you want - or clarify that there can be only one.

Comment: Oh, sorry forgot to mention there are several arcs and several conflicts. I didn't want to put all the code because it is huge. Edit: The `arc` I want has the same id as `g_arc`

Comment: So when inside `g_arc` I need to get the "value" which is inside `arc`, so I need to compare the id's

Comment: In your example, `g_arc` has `id="5561"` and `arc` has  `id="5595"`. In general, when you have matching `id` values, it is best to use a [**key**](https://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xslt-19991116/#key) to get the value from the corresponding node.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm gonna try it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following **simplified** example:

**XML**

```
<pnml>
    <net>
        <arc id="123">
            <inscription>
                <value>12</value>
            </inscription>
        </arc>
        <arc id="456">
            <inscription>
                <value>45</value>
            </inscription>
        </arc>
        <arc id="789">
            <inscription>
                <value>78</value>
            </inscription>
        </arc>
        <conflict>
            <group>
                <g_place>
                    <g_arc id="789"/>
                </g_place>
            </group>
        </conflict>
        <conflict>
            <group>
                <g_place>
                    <g_arc id="456"/>
                </g_place>
            </group>
        </conflict>
        <conflict>
            <group>
                <g_place>
                    <g_arc id="999"/>
                </g_place>
            </group>
        </conflict>
    </net>
</pnml>
```

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:key name="arc" match="arc" use="@id" />

<xsl:template match="/pnml">
    <results>
        <xsl:for-each select="net/conflict/group/g_place/g_arc">
            <xsl:variable name="value" select="key('arc', @id)/inscription/value" />
            <result id="{@id}">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="$value">
                        <xsl:value-of select="$value" />
                    </xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>1</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </result>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </results>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<results>
  <result id="789">78</result>
  <result id="456">45</result>
  <result id="999">1</result>
</results>
```

Answer (score 0):

Any path you use to select the `arc` needs to be relative to the current node (you can use `../` or `ancestor::` to go back up the tree). Or you can use an absolute path.

In this case, I think a a relative path would be more appropriate since I'm guessing you need to operate within the bounds of a single `<net>` element:

```
<xsl:variable name="arcValue"
              select="ancestor::net/arc[@id = $arc_id]/inscription/value" />
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="$arcValue">
        <xsl:value-of select="number($arcValue)" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:text>1</xsl:text>
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer but it still doesn't work. Before the code above I have the following: `<xsl:for-each select="../conflict/group">
 <xsl:variable name="group_id" select="@id" />
      <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="$group_id = 0">
      <xsl:text>          If </xsl:text>
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
             <xsl:text>          Elsif </xsl:text>
      </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>


      <xsl:value-of select="./g_transition" />
      <xsl:variable name="transition_id" select="@id" />
`